# In React, I want to use 'useEffect', but what i get is an error page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I know when i want to use useEffect with props, need to put props into [].

```
function MyFavourite() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [checkLoading, setCheckLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    getFavourite();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
    setCheck(data);
  }, [data]);

  const getFavourite = async () => {
    await favouriteApi
      .myFavourite()
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  const setCheck = (data) => {
    if(data.length < 1){
    setLoading(true);
    } else {
    setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

what i want to do is that when return data is an empty array, want to show a warning sign.
and when i get data array, want to show the data.

when 'loading'is false, shows data.
when 'loading' is true, shows a warning sign.

so i used two useEffect functions.
the one is getting data function and the other one is to consider loading status.

when you look at the second 'useEffect'

```
useEffect(()=>{setCheck(data);},[data]);
```

i put data into deps. so i can use.
but at setCheck function says cant read data.length property.
it means that data is not came yet
but i can see the data by using console.log(data);

please help me with this

Answer (score 2):

On the first call of your `useEffect`, you data's value is `null`.

Instead, only call setCheck once there is data.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(data) {
       setCheck(data);
    }
  }, [data]);
```

Or better yet, to make sure you have data, you can call your `setCheck` inside the `.then` block of your `favouriteApi` api call. That way, you'd have less effects to worry about